# What set did this Technic container come from?

Tags: part-identification, technic

This box has a lot of Technic LEGO pieces but I don't know which set this is from. The box is small, violet.[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's [Container, Throwbot / Slizer 'Flying' Case Lid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32176)

This item in Purple color was available in [two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=32176&colorID=24&in=A).

Comment: Thanks you very much, again , Alex.